# Load image in jsp from different URL but same domain?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, static-content, imageurl

I am trying to load an image into my jsp located in the '*files*' folder on the class path.

[image]

The URL of the .jsp in which I try to load images is http://www.my-webapp.com/authenticated/dashboard.
The problem is that jsp is searching for the '*files*' folder inside the '*authenticated*' folder instead of class path.

This is the URL I get when I use the 'Inspect Element' of Google Chrome:

[image]

How can I tell my jsp to search for '*files* folder on classpath but not in '*authenticated*' folder?

**My struts.xml** (if needed):

```
<package name="account" namespace="/authenticated" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="dashboard" class="DashLoader" method="execute">
        <result name="success">/authenticated/dashboard.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean different webapps? I am trying to load the image from the same application but different url pattern.

Comment: @ScaryWombat No they're not, based on the image above they're two directories at the root level of a single webapp's content.

Comment: The correct URL is simply `/authenticated/files/klichko...`. Since you don't show the JSP it's impossible to help, but you should be using an *absolute* path, not a *relative* path. If you *really* mean "class path" then you'll have to be more specific because it doesn't make much sense on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default content loader allows you to serve static content from the classpath. This loader handles URLs that start with `/static`. So, if you put your image on the classpath under the `files` package, then it could be accessed like `/static/files/image.jpg`.

You can read more about static content loader and configuration settings in the docs for [Static Content](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/static-content.html).